# No IPv6 connectivity to Docker container outside of host

Tags: networking, iptables, docker, ipv6

I have an IPv6 native container running a small webapp on port 8000.

On the Docker host, I can access the webservice using the global IP, but get 'connection refused' when connecting from another host. However, the container can be pinged from the other host.

The service in the container works

```
# curl "http://[2a01:4f8:10a:2cc5:0:242:ac11:2]:8000"
I'm b6032b33bc12
```

However, running from another host:

```
{2.1.5p273} curl "http://[2a01:4f8:10a:2cc5:0:242:ac11:2]:8000"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 2a01:4f8:10a:2cc5:0:242:ac11:2 port 8000: Connection refused
```

Yet, the ipv6 address is pingable:

```
{2.1.5p273} ping6 2a01:4f8:10a:2cc5:0:242:ac11:2
PING 2a01:4f8:10a:2cc5:0:242:ac11:2(2a01:4f8:10a:2cc5:0:242:ac11:2) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2a01:4f8:10a:2cc5:0:242:ac11:2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=0.385 ms
64 bytes from 2a01:4f8:10a:2cc5:0:242:ac11:2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=0.452 ms
```

What have I missed?

Some more details about my environment:

```
# docker -
Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e
```

The daemon uses the following args to enable ipv6:

```
--experimental=true --ipv6 --fixed-cidr-v6=2a01:4f8:10a:2cc5::2/64
```

The host has a routed ipv6 `/64` subnet, which is has one ip allocated to `eth0`, and the remaining subnet on `docker0`.

```
# ifconfig
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:c8:f8:5c:7b
      inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::1/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: fe80::42:c8ff:fef8:5c7b/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2a01:4f8:10a:2cc5::1/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:129 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:121 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
      RX bytes:9536 (9.3 KiB)  TX bytes:11130 (10.8 KiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:1b:0e:c4:3d:a1
      inet addr:88.99.148.135  Bcast:88.99.148.191  Mask:255.255.255.192
      inet6 addr: fe80::921b:eff:fec4:3da1/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2a01:4f8:10a:2cc5::2/128 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:107917 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:25223 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:143498170 (136.8 MiB)  TX bytes:2953043 (2.8 MiB)
      Interrupt:16 Memory:f7000000-f7020000
```

The container has a global ipv6

```
docker exec b6032b33bc12 ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ac:11:00:02
      inet addr:172.17.0.2  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::42:acff:fe11:2/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2a01:4f8:10a:2cc5:0:242:ac11:2/64 Scope:Global
```

Routing for ipv6 is in place, and appears to work:

```
# ip -6 route
2a01:4f8:10a:2cc5::2 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
2a01:4f8:10a:2cc5::/64 dev docker0  proto kernel  metric 256
2a01:4f8:10a:2cc5::/64 dev docker0  metric 1024
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev docker0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev veth0fbfa39  proto kernel  metric 256
default via fe80::1 dev eth0  metric 1024
```

The host has outbound connectivity:

```
# ping6 google.com
PING google.com(fra16s20-in-x0e.1e100.net) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fra16s20-in-x0e.1e100.net: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=5.08 ms
```

As does the container

```
# docker exec b6032b33bc12 ping6 google.com
PING google.com(fra16s20-in-x0e.1e100.net) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fra16s20-in-x0e.1e100.net: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=5.00 ms
64 bytes from fra16s20-in-x0e.1e100.net: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=5.00 ms
```

I suspect there's an iptables issue:

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate     RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:8000
Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

And the ipv6 equivalent:

```
# ip6tables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking through your entire configuration I don't see anything wrong in it.

Everything I have used from Hetzner came with only a link prefix and no routed prefix. But I tried `mtr` from a machine outside of Hetzner's network, and the output looks like `2a01:4f8:10a:2cc5::/64` really is a routed prefix.

Assigning a single address from your routed prefix on your `eth0` is a bit unusual. But since you did assign it as a `/128` that is still a valid configuration. And if your server came with only a routed prefix and no link prefix, then assigning a `/128` in that way is a sensible configuration.

Since I couldn't find any problems in your configuration, I instead tried to reproduced the problem from my machine, and I couldn't.

```
$ curl "http://[2a01:4f8:10a:2cc5:0:242:ac11:2]:8000"
I'm b6032b33bc12
```

That leads me to the conclusion that the problem likely lies on the machine where you ran that `curl` command (or on the network it is attached to).

Since you didn't tell us anything about that machine, I cannot say more specifically what the problem is. What you can try is to compare the output of these two commands:

```
traceroute 2a01:4f8:10a:2cc5:0:242:ac11:2
traceroute -p 8000 2a01:4f8:10a:2cc5:0:242:ac11:2
```

Here I am using the `traceroute` package on Ubuntu 16.04. Other `traceroute` versions may need different arguments.